# Is there a way to inject an Item/DataTemplate into a custom Style or UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol

### Read update for a solution

I have a small WPF Application with several small game clones such as Minesweeper, Connect 4, Tic Tac Toe among others.

Common for all of these is that they are all a uniform grid of squares, each square is controlled by a button.

For each of these games I have defined a UserControl with a UniformGrid ItemsPanelTemplate in their XAML.

The only place they differ is the DataTemplate used:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- Button that fit the specific need of the game -->
    </DataTemplate>           
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

To avoid repetition I wanted to create a UserControl which has a DataTemplate dependency property (and has an ItemsControl defined in the XAML named itemscontrol):

```
public DataTemplate DataTemplate
{
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(DataTemplateProperty);
    set => SetValue(DataTemplateProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BoardGameControl));

public BoardGameControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    itemscontrol.ItemTemplate = DataTemplate;
}
```

Which I tried to use in my application like so:

```
<controls:BoardGameControl>
    <controls:BoardGameControl.DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Hi"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:BoardGameControl.DataTemplate>
</controls:BoardGameControl>
```

I have tried some other approaches as well but none have worked.

How can I avoid having to define a new ItemsControl for each game and instead have a UserControl or Style that simply accepts a different Button depending on the situation?

## Update

I combined both the solution I marked as **Accepted** and the comment by @Joe on this post.

Instead of a UserControl I created a Custom Control with my desired properties and then styled in in the Generic.xaml file to my liking. I also removed the DataTemplate property from my Custom Control and instead added DataTemplates in my App.xaml for each different VM.

Below you will find the code behind and style of my new Custom Control.

```
public class GameBoardControl : Control
{
    public int Columns
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Columns), typeof(int), typeof(BoardGameControl));

    public int Rows
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(RowsProperty);
        set => SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Rows), typeof(int), typeof(BoardGameControl));

    static GameBoardControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GameBoardControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GameBoardControl)));
    }
}
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:GameBoardControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:GameBoardControl}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:GameBoardControl}}}"
                                         Rows="{Binding Rows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:GameBoardControl}}}"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that I always bind the ItemsSource to Squares, I am able to do this since all of my games have an ObservableCollection called Squares where the Square View Models are stored.

Example of a DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mvvmtoolkit:MemorySquareVM}">
        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:GameBoardControl}, Path=DataContext.PressSquareCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Background="{Binding Position, Converter={local:PositionToColorConverter}}"
                Style="{StaticResource MemoryButton}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the `DataType` for the `DataTemplate`?  Is it different for each "game clone"?  If it is you could create a `Style` for your control and then give that Style a `Resources` section (literally specify `Style.Resources`.  Then, in the Resources section you could create a default `DataTemplate` for each type.    As long as the different Data type is used as some kind of Content, it could all work

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, you could just give the `ItemsControl` a `Resources` section to do the same thing.  But again, you need a different data type to base them on.

Comment: @Joe
The DataType is always extends ObservableObject but other than that are different for each game. 

I am not super familiar with using Styles and Resources yet but it sounds like the solution I use for changing views for the different games where each of my game VMs has a DataTemplate with the corresponding view.

Do you suggest I could do the same s.t. each different DataType of the squares would have their own DataTemplate where I could define how the button looks and functions?

If you look at the answer I marked as "Accepted", which solution would be preferable?

Comment: The solution you accepted uses `ItemTemplate`to limit yourself to one `DataTemplate` for all items.   But as I think you've realized,  If you do not specify an `ItemTemplate` for the ItemsControl,, then the default `DataTemplate` for each item's type will be used.  If you then create a default` DataTemplate` for each such VM type and put it somewhere appropriate it will be picked up and used for each item. Because each item's container is a WPF  `ContentControl` and that's how `ContentControl` works;  It tries to use the default `DataTemplate` for its Content if you do not specify one.

Comment: My original suggestion about using a `Style` with its own resources might have been useful if you had used this many places and another case in which you wanted to use a completely different set of  `DataTemplate`s for each distinct item type.  e.g., maybe in one case your controls shows detailed information about each item and in another case it just shows summary info.  If you were to defined two different styles to the control each of which had a `Resources` section with different default detail/summary `DataTemplate`s for each type, you achieve that merely by applying the right `Style`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, then you need to slightly change the implementation: You should not use value assignment in Code Behind - Instead, you need to use binding in XAML.

```cs
public BoardGameControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // itemscontrol.ItemTemplate = DataTemplate;
}
```

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{Binding DataTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BoardGameControl}}}">
```

I also strongly advise in such cases (when properties are added to an element, its behavior is changed, etc.) to use not UserControl, but Custom Control.

> why my implementation did not work?

Implementation on Sharp:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BoardGameControl),
         new PropertyMetadata((d, e) => ((BoardGameControl)d).itemscontrol.ItemTemplate = (IEnumerable) e.NewValue));

public BoardGameControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // itemscontrol.ItemTemplate = DataTemplate;
}
```

> I would make a Custom Control, however I do not know how to implement the logic of an ItemsControl / UniformGrid myself

If you work in the Studio, then select "Add" -> "Create element" in the context menu. A combo box will appear and select "Custom Control WPF" from it.
You will have a class code derived from Control. Add properties and the logic of behavior you need to it.
And the "Themes/Generic.xaml" file will also be created - this is the default theme. This theme will have a template for your element - edit it as you need.

Comment: This worked, may I ask why my implementation did not work? I would make a Custom Control, however I do not know how to implement the logic of an ItemsControl / UniformGrid myself. I do understand why a UserControl in this case might not be ideal.

Comment: When XML is processed, an instance is first created and then its properties are set.
You get the value of `DataTemplate` property in the constructor, and at that moment this own is null. To implement on Sharp, you need to set `PropertyChangedCallback` method when declaring the property and assign a value to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property in it.

Comment: Read the additions to my answer.

Comment: I think I came up with a something that matches your suggestions if you look at the additions to my question @EldHasp . Feel free to correct me if I did a poor job, I'd love to learn if there are better ways.

Comment: "> I combined both the solution I marked as Accepted and the comment by @Joe on this post."  In such an implementation, I do not see how your implementation option differs from just a DataTemplate. Perhaps you over-truncated your example.

Comment: You mean remove the style for GameBoardControl and instead just have a datatemplate for it, since the Style itself it just a template?

Comment: Yes. Quite right.